# GroupCount order by

Tags: java, gremlin, simplegraph

The Unit test code from the simplegraph-core testsuite below displays the region count of airports but it is not ordered as I would have expected.

The result starts with:

```
NZ-BOP=  3
MZ-A=  1
MZ-B=  1
IN-TN=  5
MZ-N=  1
PW-004=  1
MZ-I=  2
BS-FP=  1
IN-TR=  1
MZ-T=  1
BJ-AQ=  1
GB-ENG= 27
```

I looked into

- [Gremlin group by vertex property and get sum other properties in the same vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45094967/gremlin-group-by-vertex-property-and-get-sum-other-properties-in-the-same-vertex)
- [Gremlin query for groupcount of last value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42016541/gremlin-query-for-groupcount-of-last-value)

and searched for "GroupCount" in questions tagged gremlin to no avail

**What is necessary to fix the ordering?**

**Unit Test**
see also https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.simplegraph/blob/master/simplegraph-core/src/test/java/com/bitplan/simplegraph/core/TestTinkerPop3.java

```
  @Test
  public void testSortedGroupCount() throws Exception {
    Graph graph = getAirRoutes();
    GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();
    Map<Object, Long> counts = g.V().hasLabel("airport").groupCount()
        .by("region").order().by(Order.decr).next();
    assertEquals(1473, counts.size());
    for (Object key : counts.keySet()) {
      System.out.println(String.format("%s=%3d", key, counts.get(key)));
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to order the `values` with `local` scoping:

```
g.V().hasLabel("airport").
  groupCount().
    by("region").
  order(local).
    by(values, Order.decr)
```

With `local` scoping you order within the current traverser (i.e. order the contents of each `Map` in the traversal).

```
  @Test
  public void testSortedGroupCount() throws Exception {
    Graph graph = getAirRoutes();
    GraphTraversalSource g = graph.traversal();
    Map<Object, Long> counts = g.V().hasLabel("airport").groupCount()
        .by("region").order(Scope.local).by(Column.values,Order.decr).next();
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/49361250/1497139
    assertEquals(1473, counts.size());
    assertEquals("LinkedHashMap",counts.getClass().getSimpleName());
    debug=true;
    if (debug)
      for (Object key : counts.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%s=%3d", key, counts.get(key)));
      }

  }
```

will then show:

```
US-AK=149
AU-QLD= 50
CA-ON= 46
CA-QC= 44
PF-U-A= 30
US-CA= 29
```

Comment: This is the groovy solution. I tried to translate this to java and only found the Scope.local for the order(...) part. for by() I didn't find a two parameter function that fits your answer. Only doing have of your proposal leads to a class cast exception. See the modified testcase I just checked in.

Comment: it's not a "Groovy" answer really. Static imports are a construct of Java as well as groovy so there is nothing particular to groovy there. you need `org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Column` for `values`.  Here's the overload of `by()` you would be using: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/current/core/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/dsl/graph/GraphTraversal.html#by-java.util.function.Function-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: I have almost this exact example in the tutorial/book in case it helps
http://kelvinlawrence.net/book/Gremlin-Graph-Guide.html#countrydist

Answer (score 0):

Using the Gremlin language only, you can do it using the unfold method. This may be useful if you need to run your query by the REST API.

```js
g.V()
  .hasLabel("airport")
  .values("region")
  .groupCount()
  .unfold()
  .order()
  .by(values)
```